# Bloquear descarga PDF en Codeigniter

Tags: php, html5, css3, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Codeigniter version 2.2.6, y tengo que mostrar un PDF en web, esto ya lo hice de la siguiente manera

```
<embed src"ejemplo.pdf#toolbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px">
```

el problema es que quiero que el PDF **no se descargue** que solo se visualice.
Como veran he agregado el `#toolbar=0` y esto quita las opciones de guardar impirmir, etc pero si le doy clic derecho sale la opcion "Guardar como" y esto es lo que quiero evitar. Alguna solución por favor.

Comment: Regla de oro de la seguridad: No se pueden "securizar" los elementos que no controlas. Si envías un PDF al PC de un usuario, habrá métodos para que el usuario se lo descargue. Al fin y al cabo, el servidor solo ve una petición HTTP y no sabe de donde viene.

Comment: O dicho de otra forma, tú envías unos bytes a un programa cliente para que el programa cliente los procese. Pero si el programa cliente no está controlado, podrá hacer con esos bytes lo que quiera.